# Avoiding conflict resolutions when working with submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

How can I avoid wasting my time on conflict resolutions when working with Git submodules? I have the following scenario:
Let's say I work on branch X of Project_A repo which is using submodule Project_B (currently pointing to master branch of it). I have also made changes to to Project_B on branch X. I want to test my code, so I want to change submodule pointer on branch X of Project_A to branch X of Project_B. I don't currently care about conflicts or merging, I simply want Project_A submodule pointer to point to Project_B branch X instead of master.
Is that possible, and if yes, how can I do it?